# viewDidAppear not firing

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I know this has been asked but I've tried all the solutions to no avail.

One of the tabs of my application is Logs

When it is selected a log viewcontroller with a list of logs is displayed

I have a "+" on the top menu bar to add new logs

When I select it I push the add log view controller on the stack

I add a new log - I then take the back button

when I return to the table the list is not updated

I wanted to reload the data in the table upon returning to the first view controller but
neither viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear are fired upon returning to the table

Since the first screen is oblivious

I added these to the second screen in an attempt to find any action occurring when the back button

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear{
 NSLog(@" whered it go");
}

-(void)viewDidDisAppear
{
NSLog(@" disapeeeeeearing");
}

- (void)backAction {
NSLog(@" WHAT ABOTU THIS       ");
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
[viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
NSLog(@"is ANY of this Happening");
}
```

NONE of these fire when the add screen disappears no NSLog printed

From what I've read the lack of response on the first screen is  because the log table never really left the stack .

This didn't happen when I did this on another tab (different part of the app)

Whats different about this tab is the add log view controller has 5 subviews and can call modals (though it fails even when I don't call them)  - I'm guessing it has something to do with that.

The call from the logs to the add logs

```
AddViewController *controller =[[AddViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"AddViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.passString= newText;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Don't have any code for the return it just clicking on the back button at the top of the screen.

sorry for any misspellings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you aren't using the correct methods.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear{
     NSLog(@" whered it go");
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewDidDisAppear
{
    NSLog(@" disapeeeeeearing");
}
```

Aren't declared anywhere. I believe what you meant to write was:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"About to disappear");
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"Did disappear");
}
```

Methods are case sensitive, and you can't just leave out arguments and expect it to work.

Comment: You are absolutely correct sir - both fired on exiting second program. Thank you very much. I've already apologized to the compiler.

Comment: @0x77777777  please don't misunderstand me I am grateful for the help (and correction) I should just move along, but I am truly puzzled: Once I correctly put those 2 methods in the second view controller (the add),  the viewDidLoad in the first view controller started firing! How did evoking these (or the supers) in one view controller  evoke (or awaken)viewDidLoad in another view controller? Once again thanks for your help.